# What are the installation files for cygwin?

Tags: software-installation, cygwin

For installing cygwin, it's website provides a small exe file which is to download the actual installation file from a mirror. But I don't have internet freedom on the destination computer with 64 bit windows. I can only use my phone with WiFi. Which files shall I download from this mirror? cygwin.mirror.constant.com

Answer (score 3):

The Cygwin Setup allows to download packages without installing and also to install from a local directory.
If you perform the first on a computer with internet access and download the files on a USB stick and the second on the computer without internet access, you can solve your problem

[image]

[image]

Pay attention that the full download is ~ 8 GB, and by default only a base installation is selected. Choose what you need on the second computer at download time.